# How do you fix view for zoomed in components in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, view, properties, visual-studio-2017

I had been using Visual Studio for a while now but this is the first time I had encountered this issue. I am not sure how this happened but as you can see my whole workspace is not looking pretty good. I can't adjust the view by using (Ctrl+scroll). When I adjust zoom view by 50 or 100% only the components in control flow adjusts.

Here is the default format when I opened the app.
[image]

And here is when I try to zoom out.
[image]

I hope anyone can help me because I can't work properly.
Thanks.